# Overriding user profile page with a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, profile, user

I need to override the User Profile page with my custom Visualforce page where I will show the user information. So when the user clicks "My Profile" link on the top right, they will be directed to the vf page instead of a the standard user profile page.

I need to know if:

1) Is this possible?
2) If yes then how do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You cant do this short of DOM manipulation sidebar hacks. I would not recommend that.  Were would permissions be administered if you remove the profile page?

Comment: What basically I wanted to do was to change the css styling of the standard user profile page. It seems that it cannot be done so I thought maybe I could turn it into a visualforce page with my custom css.

Answer (score 3):

Are you attempting to do this for all users or just a subset? If a subset, and they don't need standard Salesforce, you could go with a Community. With that, you have the ability to adjust the look and feel of the profile page to some degree (http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities/).

If not, there was a chatter profile page "Jailbreak" contest on CloudSpokes a couple of years ago. You can find the winner's solution here: https://github.com/cloudspokes/chatter-profile-jailbreak/blob/master/docs/Chatter_Jailbreak_README.txt

Just as Phil R pointed out, it involves javascript DOM manipulation so YMMV.

Comment: I am trying to customize the css for all the users. I dont even want to touch the functionality, just changing the css, thats all.